# How to check request type in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So imagine I want to have a function that depending on the request type does different things. For example, if some controller's method requires user to be logged in and the user is not, I want to either redirect the user, if it's an `html` request or return `javascript` or `json` response for `javascript` and `json` requests respectfully.

For those that are familiar with RoR I want something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { ... render some html ...}
   format.js { ... render javascript ...}
   format.json { ... render json ...}
 end
```

How would I do something like that in Phoenix framework? I can probably pattern match on `Plug`'s connection `req_headers` or something, but I wonder if there is a preferred way to do that?